# Consumir SOAP em Flutter, armazenando Cookie

Tags: flutter, soap, dart

Bom dia a todos, estou com uma dificuldade, preciso consumir um WS em SOAP, quando eu utilizo o Postman funciona, porem quando eu tento trabalhar com os dados no Flutter, não está dando certo, creio que seja algo no corpo da mensagem, será que alguém já passou por isso ?

**No Flutter**, **o status = 0** quer dizer que não autentiquei, o **status = 1** retorna uma chave, na qual devo armazenar para as posteriores solicitações

```
Future<void> _getAuth() async {
    String headerAuth = "<serviceRequest serviceName='MobileLoginSP.login>'" +
        "<requestBody>" +
        "<NOMUSU>juliano.conceicao</NOMUSU>" +
        " <INTERNO>1d9fc5e6</INTERNO>" +
        "</requestBody>" +
        "</serviceRequest>";

    final response = await http.post(
      "http://172.30.0.6:8280/mge/service.sbr?serviceName=MobileLoginSP.login",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml",
      },
      body: headerAuth,
    );

    print("body: ${response.body}");
  }
//resposta do Body

I/flutter (10728): cocokie: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
I/flutter (10728): <serviceResponse serviceName="MobileLoginSP.login" status="0" pendingPrinting="false" transactionId="3EAFA46D5B5470393F3858D97ADD025B"><statusMessage><![CDATA[RWxlbWVudCB0eXBlICJzZXJ2aWNlUmVxdWVzdCIgbXVzdCBiZSBmb2xsb3dlZCBieSBlaXRoZXIg
I/flutter (10728): YXR0cmlidXRlIHNwZWNpZmljYXRpb25zLCAiPiIgb3IgIi8+Ii4=
I/flutter (10728): ]]></statusMessage></serviceResponse>
```

**Utilizando o Postman**

```
POST: http://172.30.0.6:8280/mge/service.sbr?serviceName=MobileLoginSP.login 
Body:
<serviceRequest serviceName="MobileLoginSP.login">
  <requestBody>
    <NOMUSU>juliano.conceicao</NOMUSU>
    <INTERNO>1d9fc5e6</INTERNO>
  </requestBody>
</serviceRequest>

Body de Retorno note status = 1 de sucesso

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<serviceResponse serviceName="MobileLoginSP.login" status="1" pendingPrinting="false" transactionId="2BC5A4E9EC98C6ECB75AC998E2E74AA5">
    <responseBody>
        <jsessionid>C3LeL-J1x-hQKSn7-TUxoOjow7BXyL8Cfn4kM8sP</jsessionid>
        <idusu>MTM5
</idusu>
        <callID>7278E887855ACEE0AACA2451A5C681F9</callID>
    </responseBody>
</serviceResponse>
```

Answer (score 3):

Olá,
acho que você errou a posição do **'**, colocou depois do login> o **'**, e ficou com a sintaxe errada e tente inverter as aspas por apóstrofos. As aspas você deixa para "MobileLoginSP.login". Veja abaixo.

```
 String headerAuth = '<serviceRequest serviceName="MobileLoginSP.login">' +
            '<requestBody>' +
            '<NOMUSU>juliano.conceicao</NOMUSU>' +
            ' <INTERNO>1d9fc5e6</INTERNO>' +
            '</requestBody>' +
            '</serviceRequest>';
```

Answer (score -3):

O motivo do erro do código e uma das possíveis soluções já foi explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/476320/196424).

No dart é possível utilizar strings multilinhas para melhor controle dos caracteres envolvidos na string. Ex.:

```
String headerAuth = '''
<serviceRequest serviceName="MobileLoginSP.login">
<requestBody>
<INTERNO>1d9fc5e6</INTERNO>
</requestBody>
</serviceRequest>
''';
```

Obs.: Evitar o uso de "tabs" numa nova linha, ao menos que seja necessário.